# Is there a dataset having multiple files and multiple data formats (JSON+CSV+XML) for research purpose etc.?

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, uses-of-open-data

I have been working on data science problems with one format(JSON or CSV).I am planning to explore datasets with multiple data formats. Any links to such datasets would be helpful.
For example:
1) Consists of related data in multiple files and formats such as CSV, Excel, XML, JSON etc.

2) Has both single and multiple records in each file. For example there is 1 file for each patient, or a

file has multiple patient records.

3) Has both single and multiple files for each record. For example, 1 patient record is split across

multiple files.

Comment: Can you [edit] and add why you would want that? It's a bit strange that you don't ask anything about content, only about form.

Answer (score 3):

[Open Hampton Roads' datahub.io](https://datahub.io/organization/open-hampton-roads) has a number of datasets with multiple file formats. At one point I would convert them to as many as possible, so you have a lot of options, including GIS data. [Here's one example of crime data in four formats](https://datahub.io/dataset/2006-summary-of-reports-for-zip-code-23696-york-county-virginia)